# Match a WGS84 coordinate

Tags: regex, coordinates

I would like to match a WGS84 coordinate system from a string.

The Coordinate is written like this:

`dddmm.sss,H`

where

```
ddd: 0-180
mm: 0-59
sss: 0-999
H: W or E
```

I tried a regex from the internet, but the match didn't work sadly. How would the regex for this look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(0[0-9][0-9]|1[0-7][0-9]|180)[0-5][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][0-9],[EW]` in [POSIX ERE](https://www.mirbsd.org/man7/re_format) and PCRE.

Use `(0[0-9][0-9]|1[0-7][0-9]|180)[0-5][0-9]\.[0-9]*,[EW]` if you're trying to parse `NMEA 0183` as the amount of fractional digits varies between devices (a reference says 2, you have 3, and I've seen a device give four digits).

Comment: My  documentation explicitly says 3 digits, and the values are always correct. I will keep that in mind though.